# Dialog.getCancelable() doesn't exists

Tags: android

Is there any way to know if a Dialog was set to cancelable `true` or `false`?

ex : `Dialog.setCancelable(true)`

How do I get its value ?

Comment: you can check dialog.isShowing()..whether it is showing on screen or not.!

Comment: just curious.. what can be the use of getcancelable

Answer (score 3):

No, the Dialog class does not have such feature in its API.

If you really need to, you can access the cancelable flag with Java reflection:

```
Field f = Dialog.class.getDeclaredField("mCancelable");
f.setAccessible(true);
boolean cancelable = f.getBoolean(yourDialog);
```

Since this is accessing Dialog class internals, there's no guarantee it will work on different versions of Android.

Of course, if you are creating the Dialog yourself, you know what parameters you have passed to it and can deduce cancelability from there.